# Take the next lower value per each group in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
          A   B       C
0  01:00:00  24  Andrew
1  01:00:00  17     Edd
2  01:00:00  12    Emma
3  01:00:00  18    Fred
4  02:00:00  38  Andrew
5  02:00:00  35     Edd
6  02:00:00  45    Emma
7  02:00:00  49    Fred
```

I want to select one row per each `A` group, with the next condition:

- Take the row whose distance to the minimum is 10. Example: In `02:00:00` group, `B` minimum is `35`, so take the row with (35 + 10= 45) `B` value.
- If (minimum + 10) doesn´t exist, take the next lower `B` value. Example: In `01:00:00` group, minimum is 12, but it doesn´t exist (12 + 10 = 22). So take the next lower B value, which is `18`.

Output should be:

```
          A   B     C
0  01:00:00  18  Fred
1  02:00:00  45  Emma
```

I´ve tried:

```
df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min') + 10 <= df['B']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for return first maximal row, also change condition to `>`:

```
i = (df.sort_values('B', ascending=False)
      .groupby('A')['B']
      .apply(lambda x: ((x.min() + 10 >= x).idxmax())))
df = df.loc[i]
print (df)
          A   B     C
3  01:00:00  18  Fred
6  02:00:00  45  Emma
```

Or first filter out all rows with higher values per groups, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `B` and last [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with keep only last dupe row:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min') + 10 >= df['B']]
df1 = df1.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
print (df1)
          A   B     C
3  01:00:00  18  Fred
6  02:00:00  45  Emma
```